# Prepend Information to Warning Messages

Tags: debugging, message-coding

I have a function running within a Do loop that sometimes issues a warning.  I'd like to prepend the warning with the loop ctr so that I can go back and debug that instance later.
Basically, I would like to modify the following line,

```
Do[i^0, {i, -1, 1}]
```

so that instead of displaying the warning:

```
Power::indet: Indeterminate expression 0^0 encountered. >>
```

it displays:

```
i=0, Power::indet: Indeterminate expression 0^0 encountered. >>
```

Where i==0 is the iteration that i^0 issues the warning.

Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here is my proposal for tagging messages with (the value of) an arbitrary expression at the time of message generation.  The tag is placed inside the the message itself.

```
ClearAll[withTaggedMsg]
SetAttributes[withTaggedMsg, HoldAll]

withTaggedMsg[exp_, label_: "When"] := Function[,
   Internal`InheritedBlock[{MessagePacket},
     Unprotect @ MessagePacket;
     mp : MessagePacket[__, _BoxData] /; !TrueQ[$tagMsg] :=
   Block[{$tagMsg = True},
         Style[Row[{label, HoldForm[exp], "=", exp, " "}, "  "], "SBO"] /. tag_ :>
           MapAt[RowBox[{ToBoxes @ tag, #}] &, mp, {-1, 1}] // Identity
       ];
     #
   ],
  HoldAll]
```

Usage:

```
Do[i^0, {i, -1, 1}] // withTaggedMsg[i]
```

[image]

```
Do[i^0, {i, -1, 1}] // withTaggedMsg[i, "At iteration"]
```

[image]

---

Note: this only works with variables that are either globally accessible or are scoped using `Block`. For example,

```
f[x_] := Message[f::brains, x]
f[5] // withTaggedMsg[x]
(* At iteration x = x f::brains: -- Message text not found -- (5) *)

Module[{x = 5},
 Message[f::brains, x]
] // withTaggedMsg[x]
(* At iteration x = x f::brains: -- Message text not found -- (5) *)

With[{x = 5},
 Message[f::brains, x]
] // withTaggedMsg[x]
(* At iteration x = x f::brains: -- Message text not found -- (5) *)

Block[{x = 5},
 Message[f::brains, x]
] // withTaggedMsg[x]
(* At iteration x = 5 f::brains: -- Message text not found -- (5) *)
```

This means that any variable that is scoped using `Block` can be used to tag a message. So, loop variables from `Do` and `Table` are accessible via this method, in addition to *any* `Block` variable. This makes it indispensable as a debugging tool.

Comment: Argh, I hadn't thought about what happens to the other fields. I do like your second method better, though; it is more readable and closer to what the OP wants. Although, the two cell output isn't to my liking, all that much, it is very nice, overall. +1

Comment: I added a fix per [Rojo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5350314#5350314).

Comment: @rcollyer thanks!

Comment: This is why I participate here: I'm having to make use of this to debug some code to load a file, and this allows me to spit out the line numbers with the errors. I'd give you another +1 if I could.

Comment: @rcollyer Glad to be of help, as always.  Thanks for letting me know, I value that a lot more than points.

Comment: You're welcome. I think that is the primary reason most of us are here. Anyway, very useful piece of code, now if I can only get my software to behave ... :P

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, suppose instead of `Do[i^0, {i, -1, 1}]` the iteration is via `Map`, eg `(1/#) & /@ Range[-10, 10]`. How to preserve message tagging w/o the named iterator?

Comment: @alan I guess that depends on what you're trying to do.  How do you envision using this, and with what syntax?  You could artificially introduce a global symbol, e.g. `Block[{i = #}, (1/#)] & /@ Range[-10, 10] // withTaggedMsg[i]`.  You could possibly use `Check`, e.g. `Check[1/#, Print["...happened with argument: ", #]] & /@ 
  Range[-10, 10];` (It may be possible collapse the printed line and the message into one.)  It seems to me that `Do` is always going to be cleaner.

Answer (score 18):

I cannot seem to make it do exactly what you want do to how messages are created, but here is a serviceable alternative using [`$MessagePrePrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24MessagePrePrint.html).  `$MessagePrePrint` formats the variables specified in the message string, and in your example, the [message](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/message/General/indet.html) has the [form](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StringForm.html)

```
General::indet = "Indeterminate expression `1` encountered."
```

where the `` `1` `` will be replaced by $0^0$, or whatever else you pass to it. It is that argument that  `$MessagePrePrint` operates on, and we can change it to suit us, as follows

```
Block[{$MessagePrePrint},
     $MessagePrePrint := ToString[StandardForm[#]] <> " at i = " <> ToString[i] &;
 Do[i^0, {i, -1, 1}]
]
```

where the output will now read "$0^0\text{ at i} =1$".

---

(Edit from Mr.Wizard)

The code above fails in *Mathematica* 7.  It seems that v7 doesn't like the fact that

```
InputForm @ ToString @ StandardForm @ HoldForm[0^0]
```

> ```
>  "\!\(\*TagBox[\(0\^0\), HoldForm]\)"
> ```

Here is a variation that is compatible with version 7:

```
Block[{$MessagePrePrint},
      $MessagePrePrint := Row@{#, " at i = ", i} ~ToString~ StandardForm &;
  Do[i^0, {i, -1, 1}]
]
```

This is still not ideal however, as every field in the message gets this tag.  For example, if you enter the spurious `Inner[f, {{1, 2}}, {3}]` you get:

> Inner::incom: Length 2 at i = 1 of dimension 2 at i = 1 in {{1,2}} at i = 1 is incommensurate with length 1 at i = 1 of dimension 1 in {3} at i = 1. >>

Comment: It seems that v7 doesn't like the fact that `InputForm@ToString@StandardForm@HoldForm[0^0]` yields `"\!\(\*TagBox[\(0\^0\), HoldForm]\)"`.  Either the form I show in my answer or `ToBoxes[ToString[StandardForm@#] <> " at i = " <> ToString[i]] &` appear to work.

Answer (score 15):

rcollyer has a nice solution. Here's another possibility using `Check` and printing the list of messages generated at the current evaluation.

```
Quiet@Block[{$OldMessages = 0}, 
        Do[Check[#^#/# &@Mod[i, 2], 
            Print@StringForm["At i=``, ``", i, $MessageList[[$OldMessages + 1 ;;]]]; 
            $OldMessages = Length@$MessageList;], 
        {i, 0, 5}]
   ];

(* At i=0, {Power::indet,Power::infy}
   At i=2, {Power::indet,Power::infy}
   At i=4, {Power::indet,General::stop,Power::infy,General::stop} *)
```

Remove the `Quiet@` if you want to see the actual messages generated.