# What is the simplest way to determine which call to a superfunction has generated a Message?

Tags: implementation-details, message-coding, error-tracking

I have a complicated function which contains many calls to `NIntegrate`, `NSolve`, `FindRoot` and other superfunctions in many places. My function is organized in such a way that every call to a superfunction is assigned to unique `Block`ed variable. Sometimes these functions produce `Messages` but it is not obvious which call has generated the message. I wish to find a straighforward way to know which call has generated the message. It would be great to include this information in the `Message` itself but just printing this information before/after the `Message` would be sufficient.

I know that [there is](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/YxTwWVL_UCg/IrKs9bhtsdkJ) undocumented function `` Internal`HandlerBlock `` which seemingly can do such tasks but I do not know how to restrict it to handle only *printed* messages.

For example,

```
Internal`HandlerBlock[{"Message", 
  If[MatchQ[#, Hold[_, True]], Print[#]] &}, 
 NIntegrate[Cos[20000 x]/Sqrt[x], {x, 0, 1}]]
```

Produces many prints but only one of them corresponds to the actually printed one `Message`.

Comment: See the answers to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8215/5), especially rcollyer's and Mr.Wizard's. You might be able to add a hook to the printed message to also display the function name

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following R.M's suggestion, and shamelessly lifting code from [the Wizard’s fine answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8219/700) there, you can use `Stack[]` and get the following:

```
SetAttributes[withTaggedMsg, HoldAll]
withTaggedMsg[] := 
 Function[, 
  Internal`InheritedBlock[{MessagePacket}, Unprotect[MessagePacket];
   MessagePacket[name__, BoxData[obj_, form_]] /; ! TrueQ[$tagMsg] := 
    Block[{$tagMsg = True}, 
     Identity@
      MessagePacket[name, 
       BoxData[RowBox[{ToBoxes@
           Style[Row[{"With stack", Stack[][[3 ;;]], Spacer[5]}, " "],
             Black], obj}], form]]];
   #], HoldAll]
```

[image: screen capture]

Comment: Ah, I even upvoted Mr.Wizard's solution but completely forgot it! Thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 3):

Finding F'x's answer a bit hard to comprehend (mainly because I'm not used to working with `BoxData` nor `MessagePacket`, but also since I didn't understand why identity was necessary there, I produced the following, which also has the advantage of producing a more useful (imho) stack, i.e. with the parameters and user defined functions printed as well, and the part of the stack that comes from the observation removed. I should note though F'x's method can easily be adapted to do the same.

```
ClearAll[withStackTraces];
SetAttributes[withStackTraces, HoldFirst];
withStackTraces::Stack = "Stack is: `1`";

withStackTraces[code_] := Internal`InheritedBlock[{Message},
  Unprotect[Message];

  Module[{inside, temp}, 
   Message[x___] /; ! TrueQ[inside] := 
    Block[{inside = True}, temp = List[x][[1]];
     If[! temp === $Off[],
      Message[x];
      Internal`InheritedBlock[{$MessagePrePrint},
       Unset[$MessagePrePrint];
       Message[withStackTraces::Stack, 
        ToString[Stack[__][[4 ;; -11]], StandardForm]]]]]];

  StackComplete@code
  ]
```

I started out with printing the stack but it turns out that the same message gets called several times before actually getting printed (I'm guessing that by some catch and rethrow mechanism) and so I got multiple outputs. This way, there is only one extra message generated. Comparison of output for both methods:

[image: The first stack is more useful and clean]