# Finding and interpreting errors

Tags: warning-messages, error-tracking

This sounds like a fairly trivial question, but I can't think of any way to solve it. I am doing an extensive parameter sampling where a set of ODEs is used together with `NDSolve` to find values of the dependent variables at certain time points. Yet, I am getting several different errors (e.g. convergence errors) when using **certain** parameters.

Thus, I would like to ask your help in getting a way to **find which parameters yield the errors**, not how to fix the errors themselves.

The algorithm uses the system of ODEs (with defined initial conditions) and defines the function to compute the concentrations at various time points. It is then used to do the parameter sampling

```
SysODEs={X'[t]==ba+k1 A - b1 X[t], Y'[t]==k2 X[t]-v1 Y[t]-k1,etc};

DFunction[{a1_,b1_,v1_,k1_},ba_]:=
    Block[{sol1,c1,c2},
    sol1=NDSolve[SysODEs/.k2->2,{X,Y},{t,0,300}];
    c1=X[100]/.sol1;
    c2=Y[300]/.sol1;
    {c1,c2}
    ]

SampleP=Flatten[
    Table[{h, j, k, l}, {h, 0, 5, 1}, {j, 0.1, 0.9, 0.1}, {k, 1,10, 1}, {l, 5, 10, 1}],3];

ParallelMap[DFunction[#, 0.1] &, SampleP]
```

**Problem:** I want to know which values of `SampleP` yield errors. Because my original functions `SampleP`, `DFunction` etc. are much more complex, I didn't include them in here (`SampleP` has size ~200 000 in my problem). Is there any way of doing it? I was thinking about some kind of `Trace`, but this will give me too much unneeded information.

**Edit:** I was searching and [found this link](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ErrorAndInterruptHandling.html) with information about the functions `MLCreateMark()` and `MLSeekMark()` that are used in `MathLink`. Maybe this helps in finding something similar in Mathematica?

Comment: How about `ParallelMap[Check[DFunction[#, 0.1],errorWith[#]] &, SampleP]`

Comment: This was answered [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8219/52). To make it work, I added `vars = {a1, b1, v1, k1};` as another `Block` variable and ran `Map[DFunction[#, 0.1] &, SampleP] // withTaggedMsg[vars]`. At issue, `a1`, etc., are not the same variable as defined in your equation because function parameters effectively have `Module` scope, i.e. they're unique, so they're not replaced. Also, `k1` is a function in the second equation.

Comment: As to how to rewrite this, I'd change `DFunction` to `DFunction[vars:{_,_,_,_}, b_]:= Block[{a1, b1, v1, k1, ba}, {a1, b1, v1, k1, ba} = vars~Join~{b}; ...`. Then, `a1`, etc., are scoped correctly.

Comment: I am yet to try it out and see, but those suggestions seem great!
@SjoerdC.deVries I tried something similar, but wasn't able to get it. Let me get on that tomorrow!

Comment: @rcollyer thanks for the very nice tips. I had searched around and didn't find that post which is indeed similar. Either way, thanks!

Comment: I can't seem to make it work with `ParallelMap`, but that's okay, you can debug using `Map`.

Comment: @rcollyer though `ParallelMap` would bring many advantages. I'm wondering if it doesn't work because by splitting computations among cores, `ParallelMap` is not sequentially computing thus affecting the way it outputs errors