# How can you link Parallel Mapping and Error tracking

Tags: parallelization, message-coding, error-tracking

Following t[his question and the comments made](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26896/finding-and-interpreting-errors), together with the information [in this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8215/prepend-information-to-warning-messages), the following code allows error tracking and debugging very nicely.

```
SetAttributes[withTaggedMsg, HoldAll];

withTaggedMsg[sym_] := Function[,
  Internal`InheritedBlock[{MessagePacket},
    Unprotect[MessagePacket];
    MessagePacket[name__, BoxData[obj_, form_]] /; ! TrueQ[$tagMsg] :=
      Block[{$tagMsg = True},
        Identity@MessagePacket[name, BoxData[RowBox[{
          ToBoxes @ Style[
            Row[{"At iteration", HoldForm[sym], "=", sym, Spacer[5]}, " "],
            Black],
        obj}], form]]
      ];
    #
  ], HoldAll];

f[var : _] :=
    Block[{arg},
    arg = var;
    1/arg
];

Map[f[#] &, Range[-2, 1, 1]] // withTaggedMsg[arg]

(*At iteration arg=0  Power::infy : Infinity expression 1/0 encountered.
{-(1/2), -1, ComplexInfinity, 1}*)
```

Now, the big problem is **how to use `withTaggedMsg` together with `ParallelMap`** instead of `Map`.

```
ParallelMap[f[#] &, Range[-2, 1, 1]] // withTaggedMsg[arg]

(*At iteration arg=arg Parallel`Protected`PacketHandler::default: Unhandled packet MessagePacket[Power,infy,BoxData[RowBox[{StyleBox[RowBox[{Power,::,infy}],
MessageName],: ,"Infinite expression \!\(1\/0\) encountered."}],StandardForm]] received and discarded from KernelObject[6,local].
{-(1/2), -1, ComplexInfinity, 1}*)
```

I don't see how I could do it, and would appreciate immensely if I could get some input in this.

Thanks!

Comment: I found this question today while retagging posts.  I don't believe I have seen it before.  Are you still hoping for an answer?

Comment: I guess not, no. Sorry if it stayed here for too long. Should I close it?

Comment: Surely it is not your fault that nobody answered.  Incidentally in 10.1.0 under Windows this appears to work: `ParallelMap[withTaggedMsg[arg][f@#] &, Range[-2, 1, 1]]`.  The inner term can also be written `withTaggedMsg[arg]@*f`.  Do these work for  you?

Comment: Indeed, it works, but it isn't as pretty as the one above (ofc, this isn't a problem): ´Parallel`Protected`PacketHandler::default: Unhandled packet MessagePacket[Power,infy,...iteration",TagBox[<<2>>],"=",0,... {GrayLevel[0], RectangleBox[{0, -1}, {2, 1}]}},
AspectRatio->1,
Frame->True,
FrameStyle->GrayLevel[0.],
FrameTicks->None,
ImageSize->{Automatic, 10.8},
PlotRangePadding->None]\),StripOnInput->False],RowBox[{StyleBox[RowBox[<<1>>],MessageName],: ,"Infinite expression \!\(1\/0\) encountered."}]}],StandardForm]] received and discarded from KernelObject[2,local].´

Comment: (sorry for the messy comment. but you can see that ´iteration,...=,0´, similarly to the code above.)

Maybe you'd like to post this as an answer?