# Is it possible to use the global definition of a symbol as part of its new local definition set in a Block?

Tags: programming, function-construction, evaluation, variable-definitions, scoping

Consider the following expression:

```
Block[{Print = CopyToClipboard}, doSomething[]]
```

Now all calls to `Print` from `doSomething[]` (and all other functions it may invoke) will copy values to clipboard rather than printing them. Suppose I want to modify this expression such that all calls to `Print` *both* copy values to clipboard *and* print them.

```
Block[{Print = (CopyToClipboard[#]; Print[#]) &}, doSomething[]]
```

I need something similar to the above, but which doesn't go into an infinite recursion and where the occurrence of `Print` within the pure function retains its global meaning that it had before the execution entered the `Block`. Is it possible?

I understand the difference between `Block` and `Module`, and I need to use `Block` to create a dynamic (rather than lexical) scoping.

Comment: Since you are augmenting a behavior, you are looking for the [Villegas-Gayley trick](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25101/52). There are many examples on this site, my personal favorite is from [Mr.Wizard](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8219/52).

Comment: @rcollyer thanks for the shout-out! :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard you're welcome. I'm tempted, if I find the time, to add to the design patterns question the most fundamental pattern in mma: there is no distinction between code and data, and that is a perfect example of it.

Comment: @rcollyer Probably you know it, but I'd like to mention that languages with this property are called _[homoiconic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity)_.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov yes, having recently learned that word ... and it has some very interesting consequences.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are looking for is the Villegas - Gayley technique:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Print},
    Unprotect[Print];
    Module[{inPrint},
       Print[arg_]/;!TrueQ[inPrint]:=
          Block[{inPrint = True},
              (CopyToClipboard[#]; Print[#])&[arg]
          ];
    ];
    your-code
]
```

Here, the `` Internal`InheritedBlock `` is used to make sure that the redefinition of `Block` remains local to your execution stack - it is also a dynamic scoping construct, but it preserves the old definitions, unlike `Block`.

Comment: StackOverflow reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5149656/618728