# How do I extend (prepend or append to) an existing TagSetDelayed rule?

Tags: replacement, introspection

I have a TagSetDelayed rule associated with, say, `tag`:

```
tag/:(tag[key_]=val_):=DoSomething[tag,key,val]
tag[7]=43
(* DoSomething[tag,7,43] *)
```

I want to modify that rule to do something *before* what it already does, preserving what it already does. Of course, the following only overrides the existing rule:

```
tag/:(tag[key_]=val_):=DoSomethingElseBefore[tag,key,val]
tag[8]=44
(* DoSomethingElseBefore[tag,8,44] *)
```

I'd like, instead, to end up with the result of this:

```
tag/:(tag[key_]=val_):=(
DoSomethingElseBefore[tag,key,val];
DoSomething[tag,key,val];
);
```

I'm not sure how to "introspect", *i.e.* "paste" the existing rule as I redefine the rule, like so:

```
tag/:(tag[key_]=val_):=(
DoSomethingElseBefore[tag,key,val];
ExistingTagSetDelayedRule[]
);
```

---

**Edit**

I realized I could use `?tag` to see a list of associated rules, but how would I extract the RHS of the appropriate form, `tag[_]=_`?

```
?tag
Global`tag
(tag[key_]=val_)^:=DoSomething[tag,key,val]
```

Comment: Coming from a C++/Tcl background I may be using wrong / ambiguous / confusing terms—please do point such out and help me improve my question.

Comment: You should check the function `UpValues`

Comment: Related: [(27165)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27165/121), [(39711)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39711/121)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy method is to use the following construct

```
tag /: (tag[key_] = val_) := Block[{didBefore = True},
   Print[{tag, key, val}];
   tag[key] = val
  ] /; Not[TrueQ[didBefore]]
```

and you get

```
tag[7] = 43

(* {tag,7,43} *)
(* DoSomething[tag, 7, 43] *)
```

Here, the `Print` was injected before your actual call. If you are puzzled now, this is OK, because the approach is not obvious. For more information please look in the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5149656/1078614) or read [here](http://library.wolfram.com/conferences/devconf99/villegas/UnevaluatedExpressions/Links/index_lnk_31.html)

To answer your second question:

> how would I extract the RHS of the appropriate form, tag[*]=*?

First you have to know which kind of rule is used. In your case you assigned it to the `UpValues` of `tag`

```
UpValues[tag]
(* {HoldPattern[tag[key_] = val_] :> DoSomething[tag, key, val]} *)
```

and of course you could (but probably shouldn't) assign these rules directly by using

```
UpValues[tag] = ...
```

#### Sidenote

If you have understand the first approach, then you can write it a bit shorter, without repeating the `=` call, because this could in reality be more complex

```
tag /: code : (tag[key_] = val_) := Block[{didBefore = True},
   Print[{tag, key, val}];
   code
  ] /; Not[TrueQ[didBefore]]
```