# Maximize[Cos[x - 1], x] is not evaluated

Tags: mathematical-optimization

No explanation needed:

```
Maximize[Cos[x + 1], x]
Maximize[Cos[x - 1], x]
```

producing

```
{1, {x -> -1 + 2 π}}
Maximize[Cos[1 - x], x]
```

Needless to say, this is pretty amusing.

Does anyone know why this is happening? I am using V10.0.2 Windows 7 64-bit, although I also verified it to occur on V10.0.1 Mac Snow Leopard (I haven't tested V9 and older).

#### Backstory

I was showing my friend how Mathematica works, and wanted to show him that the maximum of $\cos(f\,t−k\,x)$ was $1$ (he was taking an intro physics class). I applied Maximize to it, thinking I would get the answer. Hilarity ensued.

It didn't take long to find a significantly shorter minimal example.

Comment: Strange. Wonder why this works `Maximize[Cos[x - 1.], x]` giving `{1., {x -> 1.}}`

Comment: I see same behavior on 9.0.1 MacOS X 10.9.5

Comment: MMA is stupid most of the time. Dumb is an under statement.

Comment: @Nasser I think it's treating it like a "numerical problem", check `NMaximize[Cos[x - 1], x]`, gives the same answer.

Comment: Well - that's the reason for people still existing, isn't it?

Be that as it may: Call `TrigExpand[]`, then `Maximize[]//Simplify`  on the second one.

Comment: @Nasser: Yup, as Chen Yu said, according to the documentation: "If Maximize is given an expression containing approximate numbers, it automatically calls NMaximize.", so it's calling `NMaximize` and numerically finding a maximum in your example.

Comment: @Simon: Yup, that works. Still, it's baffling that two functions identical up to a translation are treated so differently. I was showing my friend how Mathematica works, and wanted to show him that the maximum of $\cos(ft-kx)$ was 1. I applied `Maximize` to it, thinking I would get the answer. Hilarity ensued.

Comment: I think it's bug. `Maximize` calculates the period as `-2 π` which it rejects since it does not satisfy `0 < -2 π < Infinity`.  Without the constraint, it gets to `ToRules[C[1] ∈ Integers && x == 1 - 2 π C[1]]`, which it rejects since it does not evaluate to rules.

Comment: Also, if you try to "calculate" the period for `Sin[x]` as `Solve[f[x + k] == f[x] && k != 0, k]` it doesn't work in a straightforward way because `ArcSin[Sin[x]]` does not simplify as `x`

Comment: Well, it seems to be fixed in Mathematica 10.2 (running on OS X here).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Oh boy, it's hard to fix this at the top level.  It should be easy for WRI to fix, though.  I hope you've reported it.  If we fix `` Periodic`PeriodicFunctionPeriod `` to return nonnegative periods, `Maximize` will work properly.  The internal code has somewhat complicated pattern constraints on the definitions. I couldn't get the [Villegas-Gayley technique](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27165/is-it-possible-to-use-the-global-definition-of-a-symbol-as-part-of-its-new-local/27167#27167) to work, so I added <s>an `Abs`</s>* a real-only version of absolute value to the top-level internal function.

```
Block[{Periodic`PeriodicFunctionPeriod},

 Periodic`PeriodicFunctionPeriod[Periodic`PeriodicFunctionDump`expr__] /; 
   Periodic`Private`PDValidExpressionQ[{Periodic`PeriodicFunctionDump`expr}] := 
  Block[{Periodic`PeriodicFunctionDump`res}, 
   Periodic`PeriodicFunctionDump`res = 
    Periodic`PeriodicFunctionDump`periodicFunctionPeriod[Periodic`PeriodicFunctionDump`expr]; 
   If[Quiet[TrueQ[# < 0]], -#, #] &@ Periodic`PeriodicFunctionDump`res /;   (* <-- the "fix" *)
    FreeQ[Periodic`PeriodicFunctionDump`res, $Failed]];

 Maximize[Cos[1 - x], x]
 ]
(*
  {1, {x -> 1}}
*)
```

I cannot be sure that such a fix won't break something.  It could be that a "negative period" is a sign of something that is used somewhere inside *Mathematica*.  Mathematically speaking, the period should be a positive number.

---

The problem, as I mentioned in a comment, is that negative coefficients on `x` results in a negative period:

```
Periodic`PeriodicFunctionPeriod[Cos[1 - x], x]
(*  -2 π  *)
```

`Maximize` checks that the period is between `0` and `Infinity`.  (So `Maximize` is assuming the mathematical notion of period.)  Since it's not, the period is discarded and the equation for the critical points is solved using `Reduce` without the constraint of the period.  `Reduce` produces the indeterminate result:

```
Reduce[D[Cos[1 - x], x] == 0, x, Reals, WorkingPrecision -> ∞]
(*  C[1] ∈ Integers && (x == 1 - 2 π C[1] || x == 1 - π - 2 π C[1])  *)
```

`ToRules` is applied to this. `Maximize` assumes that if it does not evaluate to rules, then the problem has not been solved.  `ToRules` returns unevaluated.  In any case that's the nature of the bug.  It looks easy to fix (for WRI).

---

*Update note --* I just realized my comment shows that it is possible to have complex-imaginary periods. This might lead to a case where the original fix of applying `Abs` to the period would mess things up.  I changed the fix so that only negative real numbers have their sign changed.

Comment: It does seem strange that `Maximize` checks that the period is nonnegative, unless it is actually expecting to receive negative periods for some reason. Nor is this a new phenomenon; the same results are observed all the way back to (at least) version 5.2. But without knowing their reasons for doing it this way, it's hard to assess whether this is a bug or not. Anyway, +1 for a good diagnosis.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Thanks. I'm surprised it goes back so far. I would have thought someone would have discovered it. It seems neither desirable nor hard to fix. Try ``Periodic`PeriodicFunctionPeriod[Exp[x], x]``, which yields a complex imaginary period, not a positive real. (I haven't thought of a way to get `Infinity` for a period.)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I sent a bug-report to WRI citing this page, hopefully it will get some attention.

Comment: WRI sent back this message: "Thank you for taking the time to send us this report. Since Maximize's primary domain is polynomials, I filed this
with developers as a suggestion." Personally I think it ought to be expected to work with more than just polynomials, but hopefully they'll take a look and patch it.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus I think it's hard to state a larger class of functions than polynomials for which one could guarantee that maxima will be found. It seems clear to me that `Maximize` is meant to handle this simple case. As you say, hopefully they'll fix it.  Maybe they'll look at this Q&A and see how easy (I think) it is.

Answer (score 6):

For a periodic function, specify a period or use `Solve` or `Reduce` for a general solution.

```
f1[x_] = Cos[x + 1];

Maximize[{f1[x], -Pi <= x <= Pi}, x]
```

> {1, {x -> -1}}

```
Maximize[{f1[x], 0 <= x <= 2 Pi}, x]
```

> {1, {x -> -1 + 2*Pi}}

```
{f1[x] /. #, #} &@Solve[{f1'[x] == 0, f1''[x] < 0}, x][[1]] //
 Simplify[#, Element[C[1], Integers]] &
```

> {1, {x -> -1 + 2*Pi*C[1]}}

```
f2[x_] = Cos[x - 1];

Maximize[{f2[x], -Pi <= x <= Pi}, x]
```

> {1, {x -> 1}}

```
Maximize[{f2[x], 0 <= x <= 2 Pi}, x]
```

> {1, {x -> 1}}

```
{f2[x] /. #, #} &@Solve[{f2'[x] == 0, f2''[x] < 0}, x][[1]] //
 Simplify[#, Element[C[1], Integers]] &
```

> {1, {x -> 1 - 2*Pi*C[1]}}

Comment: Thank you for the workaround by manually manipulating the expression. Still, it's silly that this is even needed in the first place; this is a high-school-level math problem, and the fact that Mathematica gets tripped up on it is really unsatisfying.

Comment: I find that you almost always get better results when you specify a range.  For some problems it's just specifying that a number is real or greater than 0.  In this case, it seems to work if you specify any range, e.g. `Maximize[{Cos[x - 1], -1000 Pi <= x <= +1000 Pi}, x]`.  My second note is that although setting the derivative to 0 and solving works most of the time, it fails on discontinuous functions.