# Detect Messages within an expression without losing the return value?

Tags: message-coding

I know that `Check[expr,failexpr]` is a mechanism to catch messages. The problem with it is that if a message is generated within `expr`, `Check[expr,failexpr]` will return `failexpr`, and the return value of `expr` will be lost. Sometimes messages are just warnings and do not imply that the return value of a computation will be garbage. So what I want is a mechanism to detect messages within an expression without losing the return value of the expression. Through this mechanism I intend to `Print` some additional information to the screen, that will allow me to debug the Message. How can I do this?

Comment: Incidentally have you seen these?: [(8215)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8215/121),
[(20367)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20367/121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can define a dynamic environment where `Message` will be overloaded. Here is one way:

```
ClearAll[withMessageDetection];
SetAttributes[withMessageDetection, HoldAll];
withMessageDetection[code_] :=
  Internal`InheritedBlock[{Message},
    Module[{inMessage, tag},
      Unprotect[Message];
      (call : Message[args___]) /; ! TrueQ[inMessage] :=  
        Block[{inMessage = True},
          Sow[{args}, tag];
          call
        ];
      Protect[Message];
      Reap[code, tag, #2 &]
    ]
  ]
```

For example:

```
withMessageDetection[Range[10][[15]]]
```

> During evaluation of In[676]:= Part::partw: Part 15 of {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} does not exist. >>

```
(* {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}[[15]],{{{Part::partw,15,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}}}}} *)
```

If you just want to print the information, you can use `Print` instead or together with `Sow` and `Reap`.

**EDIT**

A different version addressing the spec clarification in comments:

```
ClearAll[withMessageDetectionAlt];
SetAttributes[withMessageDetectionAlt, HoldAll];
withMessageDetectionAlt[code_, msgCode_] := 
  Internal`InheritedBlock[{Message},
    Module[{inMessage, messageWasIssued},
      Unprotect[Message];
      (call : Message[args___]) /; ! TrueQ[inMessage] := 
        Block[{inMessage = True},
          messageWasIssued = True;
          call
        ];
      Protect[Message];
      messageWasIssued = False;
      With[{result = code},
        If[messageWasIssued , msgCode];
        result
      ]
    ]
  ];
```

For example:

```
withMessageDetectionAlt[Range[10][[15]], Print["Message issued!"]]
```

> During evaluation of In[1423]:= Part::partw: Part 15 of {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} does not exist. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[1423]:= Message issued!

```
(* {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}[[15]] *)
```

Comment: The interface I had in mind was something like `withMessageDetection[expr1, expr2]`, which always returns the result of `expr1`, and evaluates `expr2` (ignoring its return value, but `Print` inside `expr2` still has effect) if and only if Messages are generated inside `expr1`.

Comment: @becko I think, this spec is underdesigned. What if more than one message is generated during the evaluation? Do you want to evaluate `expr2` on every generated message? Also, you will probably need to somehow pass the information about the currently generated message to the `expr2`. One way of doing this would be to use the syntax `withMessageDetection[expr1, {msginfo_Symbol,expr2}]`, where you refer to whatever symbol you pass as `msginfo`, inside `expr2`, if you need that. Another way would be to make `expr2` a function of those message parameters. Let me know which you'd prefer.

Comment: `expr2` gets evaluated only once after `expr1` has completed, if and only if `expr1` generates one or more messages. `expr2` doesn't need to know the specific messages generated by `expr1` (those will get printed to `$Messages`, so I will see them there if I have to).

Comment: @becko See my edit.

Answer (score 5):

A simple way would be to assign the value of `expr` to a variable and then return that variable after printing the messages.  For example:

```
info::values = "n was `` and d was ``";

Module[{n, d, v}
, n = 100
; d = 0
; Check[v = n / d, Message[info::values, n, d]; v]
]
```

[image: result screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

`EvaluationData[expr]` returns both the result of evaluating `expr` as well as the list of messages in various forms, Print output, and even timing information.

Example:

```
evd=EvaluationData[1/0]
During evaluation of In[85]:= Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.
Out[85]= <|Result:>ComplexInfinity,Success->False,FailureType->MessageFailure,OutputLog->{},Messages->{Power::infy},MessagesText->{                                  1
Power::infy : Infinite expression - encountered.
                                  0},MessagesExpressions->{Hold[Message[Power::infy,1/0]]},Timing->0.,AbsoluteTiming->0.001,InputString:>ToString[Unevaluated[1/0],InputForm]|>
```

You'll have to pull the result out via `evd["Result"]` but it's a very useful mechanism, introduced in version 10 in 2014, right around the time you were asking this question.