# Capturing error message information

Tags: warning-messages

Error messages returned from `SendMessage` occasionally have useful information in them.  For example:

```
SendMessage["Twitter", StringJoin@ConstantArray["a", 141]]
```

returns:

> ServiceExecute::apierr: The service returned the following error message: {{code->186,message->Status is over 140 characters.}}.

Based on the docs for `$MessageList`, I assumed I could add `err = $MessageList` to the same cell as the `SendMessage` to capture the message; however `err` is an empty list when I do so.<sup>*</sup>  Additionally, when I call `MessageList[n]` where n is the appropriate cell number, I get the name of the message `{ServiceExecute::apierr}` but not the details.

How can I go about accessing the details of the error message in this case?  [Another similar question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20367/7167) has been asked; however, it's not clear to me how the answers there apply in this case.  (And for completeness, [another good read](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8215/7167).)

---

<sup>*</sup> Executing `Plot[];err=$MessageList` does populate `err`, but I don't know why `SendMessage` does not behave in the same fashion.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the answer in your [first link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20367/7167)?  It will collect complete message information.

Comment: @Szabolcs your answer is very helpful, but I am struggling with how to implement it efficiently in my case.  If I am only concerned with errors from this one function call, is my solution to create a module that (a) initializes `messages`; (b) defines `collectMessages` (c) calls `AddHandler` (d) calls `SendMessage` and (e) calls `RemoveHandler`?  Or, would I initialize  `collectMessages` and then clear `messages` before trying to send the tweet?  I'm concerned about overhead since, ultimately, this program is being run from an RPi, making efficiency a high priority.

Comment: As a complete aside, running @Szabolcs's code gives me (for `messages[[1]]`): `Hold[Message[ToExpression::sntx, "Twitter", "Private`zztop$3...`  Excuse me while I find my dark sunglasses...

Comment: I added another answer in the linked thread, which may be of use: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96390/12