# How to find out where an error occurs?

Tags: warning-messages, debugging

I got this error when using *Mathematica*:

> ```
> Part::partw: "Part 5 of {{0.637537,0.362463},{0.00038282,0.999617},
> {0.0928437,0.907156},{0.0000222833,0.999978}} does not exist."
> ```

I know why it is generated, but the problem is my code is so lengthy and I cannot find where it comes from. Is there any syntax in Mathematica by which I can resolve my problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Start by doing a search for `[[5]]`.

Comment: Try [appending info](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8219/52) to each message.

Comment: Break your code into cells and evaluate a few lines at a time. When they all work, consolidate them.

Comment: You could sprinkle a few Assert statements through your code testing whether the Part argument is longer than the list.

Comment: Combine the function linked to by rcollyer with Stack and StackBegin.

Comment: Can you put your code here ? Then we can comment on it.

Comment: See also: `traceView` : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29339/the-clearest-way-to-represent-mathematicas-evaluation-sequence/29342#29342

Comment: I wrote a function, [debug](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8363717/565518), which implements some of the suggestions given to you in comments. You can try using it, it has been one of the best debugging tools for me. I have also included it in RLink, so you can call ``Needs["RLink`"]``, and then call ``RLink`Developer`debug[your-code]``.

Comment: Try the built-in debugger: Evaluation>Debugger with Break at messages checked.

Comment: Thanks all for your helpful comments. Since my code is a recursive one, I'd rather use "Trace" to find out what is the problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Implementation

Here is a better version of my debug function posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8363717/565518), which would print the stack on the first message generated, and abort the computation. I have used it extensively with great effect in many cases.

This constructs the nested `OpenerView` from an arbitrary expression:

```
ClearAll[openerDress];
SetAttributes[openerDress, HoldAll];
openerDress[f_[args___]]:=
  OpenerView[{
    HoldForm[f],
    HoldForm[f]@@Map[openerDress,Unevaluated[{args}]]
  }];
openerDress[x_]:=HoldForm[x];
```

This uses `openerDress` to represent stack of execution in a way that is expandable when clicked:

```
ClearAll[stackPrettify];
stackPrettify[stack : {__HoldForm}] :=
  Column @ {
    Replace[stack, HoldForm[f_[x___]] :> openerDress[f[x]], 1],
    Style[Map[Short, Last[stack], {2}], Red]
  };
stackPrettify[___] := Null;
```

This is a generator of dynamic environments with redefined functions, encapsulating the Villegas - Gayley technique:

```
ClearAll[withRedefined];
withRedefined[f_Symbol, extraCondition_, beforeF_, afterF_]:=
  Function[
    code
    ,
    Internal`InheritedBlock[{f},
      Module[{inF, dv = DownValues[f]},
        Unprotect[f];
        DownValues[f]={};
        (call:f[args___]) /; extraCondition[args] && !TrueQ[inF]:=
          Block[{inF = True},
            beforeF[args];
            call;
            afterF[args]
          ];
        DownValues[f] = Join[DownValues[f],dv];
        Protect[f];
      ];
      code
    ]
    ,
    HoldAll
  ];
```

A couple more of the helper functions:

```
ClearAll[printStack];
printStack[start_, end_]:=Print[stackPrettify[Take[Stack[_], {start, end}]]];

ClearAll[heldF];
SetAttributes[heldF,  HoldAll];
heldF[body_]:=Function[Null, body, HoldAll];
```

Finally, this is the actual debugging utility (some formatting imperfections are due to the SE markdown bug regarding the display of symbols containing `$`):

```
ClearAll[debug];                        
debug[debugSymbol_Symbol:Message, failConditionFunction_:heldF[True]]:=
  Function[
    code
    ,
    Module[{tag},
      withRedefined[
        debugSymbol,
        heldF[!MatchQ[First[Hold[##]],_$Off]],
        heldF[If[failConditionFunction[##],printStack[6, -9]]],
        heldF[If[failConditionFunction[##], Throw[$Failed,tag]]]
      ][Catch[StackComplete[code],tag]]
    ]
    ,
    HoldAll
  ];
```

#### Tests

There are several ways one can use `debug`. The default one is that it breaks on first `Message` generated, and prints for you the stack. For example, one may try something like

```
debug[] @ Sin[Range[10][[1 ;; 15]]]
```

If you have an access to the source code which you want to debug, and can modify it, you could also use it in the following way:

```
ClearAll[$debugWrapper]
$debugWrapper[arg_] := arg;
```

and

```
debug[$debugWrapper][
  Sin[Part[Range[10], $debugWrapper[ 1 ;; 15]]]
]
```

In other words, you can wrap a piece of code where you suspect a problem, in some wrapper like `$debugWrapper`, and then extract the execution stack. You can also set a condition on the first event you want to trigger. For example, the following will only trigger the second event wrapped in `$debugWrapper`:

```
debug[
  $debugWrapper, 
  Function[arg, MatchQ[Unevaluated[arg], _Span], HoldAll]
][
   Sin[$debugWrapper@Part[Range[10], 1 ;; 15]];
   Sin[Part[Range[10], $debugWrapper[ 1 ;; 15]]]
]
```

in which case, only the second event wrapped in `$debugWrapper`, will be triggered.

Answer (score 13):

Assuming your code is not too messy, you may have some luck with the built-in debugger. Go to Evaluation and check on Debugger. It will open a new panel, where you should have "Break at messages" checked.

[image]

After that, Mathematica will highlight the error for you with a green box:

[image]

Comment: Instead of relying on the green box, I like to use the "Show Stack" button.  This doesn't require the code to be present in the notebook, and can show the values of variables.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I use "Evaluate Cells" to run my code. Should I enable the "Debugger" and then "Break at Messages" before evaluating the cell or after that?

Comment: @Alireza Before evaluating.

Comment: @egwene sedai Thank you very much!